# Was or Were in a list of three

Tags: grammatical-number, articles, lists

> A man, a woman and a dog were in the park.

or

> A man, a woman and a dog was in the park.

...and what's the rule please?

Also, is there a difference if we write

> A man, woman and dog were in the park.

?

Comment: Welcome @Sighm, The answer to the question is "A man, a woman and a dog **were** in the park.  But for questions like this there is a site you will find more useful. called ELL, and they can give you the rule to follow. Best wishes  .http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

A rule that works very generally is that when the subject of a sentence refers to more than one individual, use the plural form of the verb -- otherwise, use the singular form.  So, for your example, where the subject is "a man, a woman, and a dog", if that refers to 3 individuals, the verb should be "were".  If you can imagine being in a world with creatures displaying ambiguity of sex and species, the subject might perhaps refer to just a single individual, which was at once man, woman, and dog, and then the rule says you should use "was". This latter interpretation is made more plausible when you use just one article, as in your last example.